# ASP.NET C# Search in a SQL Server Database Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, search

I'm building a portal, which isn't a blogging engine, but is quite similar to one. In SQL Server, I have a database containing a table that is the basis for the "posts". This Posts table includes the following columns:

- ID
- Author(s)
- Tags
- Title
- Markdown post content

This is my first time building such a portal, and I'd like to implement some sort of **ASP.NET search** over these rows, preferably using all of the properties (columns), except for the ID one. Also, in the long run, I'm considering the possibility of implementing a search of this and comments to those posts, which would be stored in a different table.

**Are there any open-source implementations or example code online for accomplishing this search**? If not, how can I get started? Could you point me towards some tutorials w/ sample code on how to accomplish this with ASP.NET and C#? Also, has Google (or some other company) created any things for this?

I hope my question isn't too broad or vague. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using Sql Server 2008? If so, you could leverage the [full-text search features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) built right into it.  Then it would be as simple as passing the user's (sanitized) input into a sql query.

For example, here's a query that would search  the Author, Title and PostContent fields for the user's inputted text.

```
SELECT Author, Title FROM Posts
WHERE CONTAINS((Author, Title, PostContent), @userInput);
```

SQL Server 2008 supports [different search methods too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879300.aspx), like simple token, weighted word values, synonym, proximity and prefix searches... it's pretty awesome.

Comment: Could you point me to a tutorial w/ sample code for that? Thanks!

Comment: Here's a pretty thorough walkthrough:  http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of implementing search through the use of Full-Text Search? It seems like a great scenario for it. This link might provide useful information on architecture and development of Full-Text Search. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If this is publicly exposed, you can always have google index it. Google has an [appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html) which you can purchase to do this as well.

If you dont want to roll your own you could look at:

1. [Sharepoint](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html) (regular [comes with Win 2003+] or portal server)
2. [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html) (Apache Lucene project)

If you want to roll your own, I suggest looking into SQL Server Analysis Services to build the search indexes for you on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Womp - Full text index is the way to go.  You could also look at [NLucene](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nlucene/) if you need to index more than just the database table.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to use Lucene which you can use to index all your data and build a really good search engine.
i can give more information about that if you like.